# Automatic download of Word document/pdf to user's computer

Tags: .net, activex

I need to be able to automatically save either a .doc or .pdf file, created on a web server to  the user's computer. My web application is only going to be used within an Intranet environment and all users will be using Internet Explorer.

Is there an ActiveX type control (or similar) I can create which (once the user has downloaded and installed) will allow the automatic transfer of a document?

My project has been written in VB using Visual Studio 2005, .NET version 2.0.

Many thanks!

Update:

Sorry for not explaining thoroughly enough in my original question. The scenario is as follows:

A Windows XP/7 user browses to the Intranet Web Application and clicks a button.
The button click creates a document on the Web Server.
I now need to somehow save this document in to a specific location (c:\temp) on the users computer without the users needing to perform any additional act.

Comment: How do you mean automatically? Doesn't the user have to have a browser open at least?

Comment: Who shall trigger the download? The user client or the server?

Comment: What operating system? Depending on which operating system it might not be possible to download a file without a user prompt. Why do you need the file to automatically be downloaded?  An alternative is to generate the file on the server for the given user, and generate a link to the file, so they can view the file clicking on it and/or using "Save Target As..."

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I've updated the original question to answer some of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as it's intranet environment you can write some "watcher" app and install to all local machines or offer local users to download and install it at your local site;

This app can monitor changes in some //remote/share/folder and copy new files. You can monitor only files with specified prefix in filename, for example, to allow monitoring only user-related files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the watcher app would need to know the specific filename of the document that's been created. This is why I think an ActiveX type component would be best - so the web app could place the file in the correct location itself. I'm just not sure where to start with this!